# Get all my Video On Demand VOD videos, properties, urls

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I cannot find on the Vimeo API how to get all my VOD videos with the description, title, price and the url to buy them. ondemand/pages is not really showing any useful info, neither is google.

Anybody knows the endpoint for this or how to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo API for endpoints:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints

Specifically

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/me/ondemand/pages

If you're already using this and it doesn't have the info you need, you might have to contact support and request it to be added.

Comment: This answer is completely correct! If you find it doesn't solve your problem, contact vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact and we will figure out a solution!

Comment: Already contacted Vimeo! I'm waiting for the solution so I can post it here and then upvote this comment as I guess it is what people should do hehe